# Does AVAssetWriter somehow wait for GPU rendering affecting a CVPixelBuffer to finish?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, metal, avassetwriter, metalkit

Does `AVAssetWriter` (or `AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor`) do something internally to wait for the GPU to finish modifying any pixel buffers I feed it? It seems as though it might, unless I am missing some side effect of another part of my rendering procedure, which operates roughly as follows:

1. Receive a pixel buffer inside `captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection)`
2. Create a `MTLTexture` backed by that pixel buffer using `CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage`
3. Create a command buffer and encode a compute pipeline which modifies the texture from (2). Commit the command buffer.
4. Pass the original pixel buffer to an `AVAssetWriter` by way of `AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor.append()`

Even if I forego using `MTLCommandBuffer.waitUntilCompleted()` before step 4 (or similarly waiting for the GPU to finish using `MTLCommandBuffer.addCompletedHandler`), I don't get unmodified pixel buffers written to the output video file as one might expect. To verify, I did the following:

1. Added a hugely expensive but largely pointless step to the shader that modifies each incoming texture. Something along the lines of

```
kernel void exampleKernel(texture2d<half, access::read_write> texture [[ texture(0) ]],
                          uint2 gid [[thread_position_in_grid]]) {

    // Irrelevant actual shader code here

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        outputColor.r += float(i) * 0.00000000001;
    }

    // Write outputColor back to the texture
}
```

2. Set up log entries to record

   a) When each pixel buffer is appended, along with its memory address

   b) When the command buffer modifying each pixel buffer actually completes (using `addCompletedHandler`)

The resulting log looks something like this, showing that received pixel buffers are passed on to the `AVAssetWriter` well before their respective GPU commands finish. Despite this, the output file shows all the rendering effects.

```
Appending <CVPixelBuffer 0x282b6acb0> // <--- Happens almost immediately after pixel buffer is received
Finished rendering <CVPixelBuffer [some other address]>
Finished rendering <CVPixelBuffer [some other address]>
Appending <CVPixelBuffer [some other address]>
Finished rendering <CVPixelBuffer [some other address]>
Appending <CVPixelBuffer [some other address]>
Finished rendering <CVPixelBuffer [some other address]>
Finished rendering <CVPixelBuffer 0x282b6acb0> // <--- Happens a considerable time later, once the extremely slow shader finishes executing, yet the output file contains the results of this rendering, not the unmodified pixel buffer!
```